# Problems with SHA-256 hash of file passed through PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, soap-client, sha

I'm trying to use PHP **SoapClient** to call a web service function which these two parameters (taken from documentation):

```
byte[] file,     // byte array of file
byte[] hashFile // byte array of hash SHA-256 of the original file
```

It's a XML file, but I don't have the file, i just generate its content on-the-fly with : `$fileContent = $this->xmlDocument->saveXML()`

> The problem is that when I do the call to the function the server answers: **invalid file hash**

I can't understand what's my mistake.

This is the **WSDL** part which defines these parameters:

```
<wsdl:part name="file" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
<wsdl:part name="hashFile" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
```

And this is my code :

```
<?php
function sendDocument($xmlDocument,$soapClient)
{
    $fileContent = $xmlDocument->saveXML()
    $params = [
        "file"     => getByteArray($fileContent),
        "hashFile" => getByteArray(getHash($fileContent)),
    ];
    $response = $soapClient->__soapCall("sendDocument", $params);
}
function getByteArray($string)
{
    return base64_encode($string);
}
function getHash($string)
{
    return hash("sha256", $string);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you use `__soapCall()` and not the generated method directly? Please [edit] your question to include the return value of `__getLastRequest()`. Are you sure that you need to do base64 for yourself or is it already handled by the `SoapClient` class? Also add the WSDL file you are trying to use. Actually, add a [mcve] which can be run by others which shows the error message you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending a byte array from PHP to WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986151/sending-a-byte-array-from-php-to-wcf)

Comment: You were right! SoapClient already encodes given strings with base64. Moreover The hash was not recognized becausethe server wants the "raw" hash, so I've set last parameter of hash function to true. Thank you!